# How to make a print queue dispose of a job if the printer is offline?

Tags: windows, security, printing, queue

I have just had a case where upon sending a print of a sensitive document, it went to the wrong printer, a printer that was offline because I was connected to a different (work) network. When connecting to a network the next day the print job carried on, having found the printer. However I was not notified that the job was printing or had completed, and the incorrect printer happened to be in a public place where that document could have been intercepted/seen etc.

This seems like a massive security hole, and the only answer I can think of is that the print queue disposes of jobs if the printer it is sent to is offline. Is this possible?

Comment: The massive security hole is the person who sends a sensitive print job to a public printer.

Comment: That is an unhelpful comment. Pressure situation, documents are required, if the default has changed and isn't spotted, only a sys admin type would get on that horse.

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt and type these 2 commands one at a time and hit enter each time, this will clear the print spooler of all jobs in queue.

> net stop spooler

> net start spooler

[Source of Information](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln153544/clearing-the-print-spooler-in-windows?lang=en)

Comment: What would this do for a job that is in the process of spooling or currently printing? If this were scripted to run once per minute say and clear out any jobs that have gotten stuck in purgatory, would it kill good active jobs?

Comment: This doesn't clear the print spooler jobs.  To do that, you have to stop the spooler, go into c:\windows\system32\spool\printers (admin required) and delete all .SHL and .SHD files, then restart spooler.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer